# To give someone the 411

Tags: word-usage, american-english, slang

"To give someone the 411" is short for information but is this phrase common in the US and/or in Britain and is it still up to date or outdated?

Comment: 411 is the US phone number for Directory Enquiries, I believe. It's not relevant in the UK (we use six-digit numbers starting 118, but they don't form part of any equivalent numerical phrase).

Comment: Not in Britain.

Comment: OK, that's clear now. But is this phrase still common in use or just outdated?

Comment: I have never heard it, how do you say it? Is it "four eleven"? Or the full "four hundred eleven"?

Comment: In the UK we used to dial 192 for directory enquiries -- I went to the US for ten years, and while my back was turned they changed it to the six digit 118XXX abomination.

Comment: @Anton: It's pronounced "four one one", in the same way that 911 (the emergency phone number, not the terrorist attack) is pronounced "nine one one". See [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/411).

Comment: As a Brit I've used the phrase "What's the 411?" in a similar vein to how I've used "What's the craic?" - with a slight intended ironic flair (me being neither American nor Irish).

Comment: I've heard "what's the 411?" here in the US Midwest recently but can't tell you if it's considered passé or not.  (What's "craic?" @alec?)

Comment: @Alec 'craic'? What _is_ that?

Comment: GR: About 3,200,000 results for "what's the 411?" -- (About 550,000 excl. "Mary J Blige" Music); Colloq.:  http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=411 Books: "What's the 411 for Us Army Operational Level Fires" http://books.google.co.in/books?id=PFa1NAEACAAJ

Comment: @Mitch To quote wikipedia: `"Craic", or "crack", is a term for news, gossip, fun, entertainment, and enjoyable conversation, particularly prominent in Ireland.` To quote UrbanDictionary, "What's the craic?" means: `A phrase from the Irish word craic meaning with the English/urban equivalent of: what is happening in your life since last we met./give me the 411`

Comment: I think what needs to be clarified is that the actual practice of calling 411 is becoming very outdated (most people just Google it nowadays), but the slang term “four one one” (meaning information) is still used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The urban dictionary has a [definition](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=411) for it, which is probably a good barometer for its utility in AmE slang. I'm from the western USA, and it doesn't strike me as outdated. It is, however, becoming more and more trite after movies like [Clueless](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112697/) ("Here's the 411 on Mr. Hall") made it synonymous with the [Valley Girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley_girl) dialectic of Angelinos.

Comment: Even M-W [has a definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/411)!

Comment: Found the Urban dictionary source, too, but could not assess whether its common in use or not. Now I can, thanks to you. :-)

Comment: @Andrew Leach: It was not about the meaning of the phrase, it was just ... that I couldn't assess the usability nowadays.

Comment: Perhaps it's not outdated, but I'd say it has an outdated ring to it. After all, who calls 411 anymore?

Comment: @J.R. I remember when 118 was the number you called to get the official time and temperature. I remember being shocked when it was disconnected. "What's the 1-1-8?" never caught on for "What's the time?" or "What's the temperature?" though.

Comment: +1 for triteness. I've found that as a cultural norm, it is considered girly (not just feminine) and decidedly "west coast". I would note it's also come to mean something other than it's original meaning, which was "give me the basic facts of the matter" as-in "just the facts, ma'am" (from DragNet) because that's all you can get from dialing 411 (phone number, address). In the last few decades it is often used to include more comprehensive details. It seems to be falling out of general fashion, at least partially because 411 itself is falling out of fashion.

Comment: . . . let alone trying to find a phone booth from which to call 411!

Answer (score 5):

The OED says the slang use is chiefly and originally US with quotations from 1982 to 2007, the earliest in the song "Jump to It", performed by Aretha Franklin's 1982 and written by Luther Vandross and Marcus Miller:

> We have a lot of fun
>   Don't we, girl
>   Dishing out the dirt on everybody
>   And giving each other the 411
>   On who dropkicked who this week.

Searching Twitter for ["the 411"](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22the%20411%22&src=typd), you can see it's still definitely in use, and this [map](http://twittermap.appspot.com/) only returns US results (at the time of writing).

But I'm British and I'd never heard it before, and it wouldn't make sense with the equivalent to say you'd "give someone the 118" (nor with the older 192).

Comment: It's featured several times in popular music, mostly in black genres such as R&B, e.g. Mary J Blige's "What's the 411" (1992), Demarco "411" (2012), jazzer George Duke (2014), and there was an early 00s British R&B band called 411 (who weren't very successful). So it's living on as slang particularly in black culture.

Answer (score 1):

It is an Americanism and is outdated since nobody rings information / directory inquiries anymore.

It could also be misconstrued by today's digital generation since 411 is the http error code for "length required". So giving somebody the 411 might have a whole new meaning ;-)